# How to specify the size of a Docker volume?

Tags: docker, ubuntu, jenkins, docker-compose, docker-volume

I am using Docker version 20.10.17, build 100c701, on Ubuntu 20.04.4.

I have successfully created a **jenkins/jenkins:lts** image with its own volume, using the following command:

`docker run -p 8082:8080 -p 50001:50000 -d -v jenkins_home:/var/jenkins_home jenkins/jenkins:lts`

But after installing many plugins and running many jobs on Jenkins, I kept getting a notification on the Jenkins GUI that the storage is almost full (it was almost 388 Mb).

1- What is the default size of a docker volume ? I couldn't find an answer anywhere.

2- I tried to specify the size of the volume (after deleting everything image/container/volume) using the **driver_opts** and using a docker compose file.

The **docker-compose.yml** file.

```
version: '3'
services:
  jenkins:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: ./Dockerfile
    volumes:
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
      - jenkins_home:/var/jenkins_home
    ports:
      - 8082:8080
      - 50001:50000

volumes:
  jenkins_home:
    driver_opts:
      o: "size=900m"
```

The **Dockerfile**.

```
FROM jenkins/jenkins:lts
USER root
RUN apt-get -y update && apt-get install -y lsb-release &&\
    apt-get -y install apt-transport-https ca-certificates
RUN apt-get -y install curl && \
    apt-get -y update && \
    apt-get -y install python3.10 
RUN curl -fsSLo /usr/share/keyrings/docker-archive-keyring.asc \
    https://download.docker.com/linux/debian/gpg
RUN echo "deb [arch=$(dpkg --print-architecture) \
    signed-by=/usr/share/keyrings/docker-archive-keyring.asc] \
    https://download.docker.com/linux/debian \
    $(lsb_release -cs) stable" > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/docker.list
RUN apt-get -y update && \
    apt-get -y install docker-ce docker-ce-cli containerd.io docker-compose-plugin
USER jenkins
```

I got an error that the required **device** option is not specified.
I don't want a temporary storage **tmpfs**, so i tried to specify a path on my machine. I got the error that there is no such device.

What am I doing wrong? How should I proceed?

My final target is to create a Jenkins container that has a large volume size.

Comment: Also posted on https://forums.docker.com/t/docker-compose-volume-size/126287

Answer (score 0):

You could create a volume with a specified size using this command

```
docker volume create --driver local \
    --opt type=tmpfs \
    --opt device=tmpfs \
    --opt o=size=100m,uid=1000 \
    foo
```

And use it when creating the container.

Comment: The problem with tmpfs is that it is temporary and gets deleted when/if the container is down, as per [link](https://docs.docker.com/storage/): 

**tmpfs mounts:** A tmpfs mount is not persisted on disk, either on the Docker host or within a container. It can be used by a container during the lifetime of the container, to store non-persistent state or sensitive information. For instance, internally, swarm services use tmpfs mounts to mount secrets into a service’s containers.